# jQuerymobile: The alert in mobile safari shows -- file://null

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When i put an alert in JQM in my html file and runs it into mobile safari, it shows an alert (similar to iphone alertview).The title shows: **file://(null)**

Can anybody explain ?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: Please refer to the code below:

```
$(function() {
 $('#theButton').click(function() {
    alert('The Button has been clicked');

 });
});
```

Comment: Please, put your alert box code.

Comment: @A.Magalhães: refer code above

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect jquery mobile syntax. [Here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) you will find why is ***$(document).ready(function(e) {*** and ***$(function() {*** not used in jQuery Mobile. jQuery mobile syntax should go like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).live("mobileinit", function () {
        $('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
            $('#test-button').live('click', function(e) {
                alert('Button works!');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This should work without error title.

Take a look at this fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/DE4M7/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#theButton').live('click',function() {
        alert('The Button has been clicked');
    });
});
```